# How to do nested ordering of values for stacked barplot using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want a stacked barplot of disease rates by types across 6 age groups, and I want to order the types in descendly for each age group i.e. the larger types towards the bottom. I tried the following method, but it's only ordering by the largest disease category for each age group and leaving the smaller ones unordered:

[image]

Please let me know if this doable.

Here is the data:

```
structure(list(age = structure(c(7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 
7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 
9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 
12L), levels = c("<5 years", "5-9 years", "10-14 years", "15-19 years", 
"20-24 years", "25-29 years", "30-34 years", "35-39 years", "40-44 years", 
"45-49 years", "50-54 years", "55-59 years", "60-64 years", "65-69 years", 
"70-74 years", "75-79 years", "80-84 years", "85+ years", "Age-standardized"
), class = "factor"), disease = c("infection", "infection", "infection", 
"infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", 
"infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", "diarrhoea", 
"diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", 
"diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", 
"diarrhoea", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", 
"stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", 
"stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", 
"stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "stroke", "infection", 
"infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", 
"infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", "infection", 
"infection", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", 
"CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", 
"HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", 
"HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", "HBP", 
"HBP", "HBP", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", 
"CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "CKD", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", 
"diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", 
"diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea", "diarrhoea"
), value = c(23353.7, 3.9, 23642.5, 4.4, 24538.1, 5, 28653.1, 
6, 37310.1, 8.5, 46492.1, 12.5, 62458.4, 10.4, 90531.6, 16.7, 
119950.1, 24.3, 154233.1, 32.6, 191329, 43.8, 225451.4, 60.8, 
121.5, 5, 214.7, 8.8, 404.1, 17.2, 733.9, 31.2, 1397.4, 56.5, 
2578.9, 95.2, 120830.8, 20.1, 188983.9, 34.9, 305603.5, 61.9, 
480027.2, 101.3, 759052.9, 173.8, 1048404.1, 282.6, 1.7, 0.1, 
2.2, 0.1, 3.3, 0.1, 5.6, 0.2, 10.6, 0.4, 23.9, 0.9, 14000.3, 
2.3, 20370.1, 3.8, 31359.7, 6.4, 53808, 11.4, 100193.7, 22.9, 
162747.6, 43.9, 31074, 5.2, 43067.6, 8, 66533.8, 13.5, 99766.8, 
21.1, 161156.5, 36.9, 220591.3, 59.5, 32.7, 1.4, 50, 2, 76.5, 
3.3, 126.4, 5.4, 241.4, 9.8, 458.1, 16.9, 12.9, 0.5, 19.3, 0.8, 
30.9, 1.3, 69.5, 3, 173.1, 7, 420.3, 15.5, 51.7, 2.1, 90.1, 3.7, 
159.2, 6.8, 281.9, 12, 507.1, 20.5, 859.5, 31.7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-120L), class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I tried:

```
library(ggplot2)
 
df %>%
     group_by(age) %>%
    arrange(desc(value)) %>%
     ggplot(aes(x = age, y = value, fill = disease)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90) )
```

Comment: I think you mean that the order of colors will be different between columns, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I think I found a solution from tidytext (reorder factors within a column by a value). check the comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is a very not R-like solution but i could not find any other solution to what seemed to be a very simple problem

```
df_sum |>
ggplot(aes(x = age))+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"30-34")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"35-39")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"40-44")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"45-49")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"50-54")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  geom_col(data = df_sum |> filter(str_detect(age,"55-59")),
           aes(y = value, fill = fct_reorder(disease,value)), position = "stack")+
  labs(x = "Age groups", y = "Value", fill = "Disease",
       title = "Disease spread over age groups")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::comma)+
  theme_classic(base_size = 16)+
  theme(legend.position = "top")
```

Comment: Thanks so much, RYann. This was brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

This can be easily achieved using the `group` aes to set the order of the stacks individually per age group.

To this end I first aggregate your data, re-arrange in your desired order and use a helper column, i.e. the interaction of `age` and `disease`, for which I set the order using e.g. `fct_inorder`. This helper column could then be mapped on the `group` aes:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(forcats)

df |>
  summarise(value = sum(value), .by = c(age, disease)) |> 
  arrange(age, value) |> 
  mutate(order = fct_inorder(paste(age, disease, sep = "."))) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = value, fill = disease, group = order)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, the group argument! I did such an unnecessary workaround. thank you Stefan

Answer (score 2):

[image]

```
library(tidytext)
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(df) # well, I first pasted your table to df
df |> mutate(reordered = reorder_within(disease,value,age)) |> 
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = reordered, fill = disease))+geom_col()+
  scale_y_reordered()+
  labs(y= "", x = "Age", fill = "Disease",
       title = "Disease ordered from most to least frequent per age group")+
  theme_classic(base_size = 17)+
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y = element_blank())
```

Is that ok?

Comment: I personally find the list of `Imports:` in the `tidytext` package to be more than I would want for just `reorder_within` and `scale_y_reordered`, but this appears to work. Fortunately, those two functions can easily be copied from https://github.com/juliasilge/tidytext/blob/main/R/reorder_within.R and used without needing download that package or any of its dependencies. Nice work, RYann!

Comment: (Actually, on a second look, it's just `janeaustenr` that seems unnecessary ... I think it would go better in `Suggests:` than `Imports:`, but I didn't look at the rest of the package to know for sure.)

Comment: Thank you, Ryan. On this chart, the proportional size of the individual bars is substantially different. I wanted to manually check the values by displaying the y-axis, which creates a pile of overlapped text beside the plot. Could you please have another look into it?

Comment: review new answer